# How can I paint or fill an image mask in flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, mask

Good community, I am trying to create a mask with the **image (A)**.

[image]

I am using **ShaderMask** (`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sUL66pTQ7Q`).

And up to here I think that everything is correct, but the complications come when I want to paint the mask.

I don't know how to continue, to be able to fill or paint the mask, as shown in the **image (B)**.

[image]

I am using the red color to paint and fill the mask.

*Any ideas? Thanks in advance*

Comment: It would work if your mask were with black / transparent pixels, not black / white

Comment: @pskink This is just an example, the white is really transparent. But the question is, how to paint only the black fill. I have no idea

Comment: check `BlendMode.srcATop`